# JWPlayer 6.6: hls video keeps loading forever if clicked twice on player before it starts playing

Tags: jwplayer, hlsl, jwplayer6

I this problem occurs in firefox, chrome, IE. Have not checked others. Here is demo link
http://vplayer.mindtickle.com/cfvideo.php

Click on play button. Before it starts playing, click on player again any number of times. It never plays video and keeps loading. It works perfectly if clicked only once. This problem does not occurs with mp4 videos too.

Comment: Can you update to 6.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the response from JWPlayer on email so thought of updating here.

This is bug is fixed in 6.8 version, but HLS streaming in not supported anymore in premium version of 6.8, although it was supported 6.6